# haddop version command not displaying version of hadoop, getting error

Tags: java, hadoop

I have configured hadoop 2.5.2 on Ubuntu.
I am getting error while running hadoop version command.
**usr/local/hadoop/bin$ hadoop version
Error: Could not find or load main class org.apache.hadoop.util.VersionInfo****

I have set all the JAVA_HOME,HADOOP_HOME.

I am unable to run any of the option with the help of hadoop command.

Please help me on this issue.I am beginner to Hadoop.
Thank You in advance.

Answer (score 0):

edit in .bashrc file

```
export HOME=/home/kishore
export JAVA_HOME=/home/user17/jdk
export PATH=$PATH:$JAVA_HOME/bin
export HADOOP_HOME=/home/kishore/BigData/hadoop
export PATH=$PATH:$HADOOP_HOME/bin
export PATH=$PATH:$HADOOP_HOME/sbin
export HADOOP_MAPRED_HOME=$HADOOP_HOME
export HADOOP_COMMON_HOME=$HADOOP_HOME
export HADOOP_HDFS_HOME=$HADOOP_HOME
export YARN_HOME=$HADOOP_HOME
```

also copy the above command and execute on terminal

then

```
$ hadoop version
Hadoop 1.0.4
Subversion https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/hadoop/common/branches/branch-1.0 -r 1393290
Compiled by hortonfo on Wed Oct  3 05:13:58 UTC 2012
From source with checksum fe2baea87c4c81a2c505767f3f9b71f4
```

let me know if not solved;